# How to dynamic height UIView on UITablewView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have UITableViewController and I insert UIView on top with elements in view. I get problem with height of UIView. All UIlabel are multiline 0 for dynamic height. I want to make UIView height flexible with respect to UILabel in view (by attach image below). I have made it using storyboard and set autolayout but doesn't work for me. Can I make it ? Thank a lot!

[image]

Comment: Can you describe which UIView height you want to make dynamic and with respect to which UILabel height?

Comment: @AshishVerma I want to make UIView over UITableViewCell dynamic (UILabel/UIImageView in UIView) and every UILabel in this view have multiline 0.